# OpenCv_Python - Convert Frame Sequence To a Video

Tags: resize

I am a newbie in OpenCV using Python. I am currently working with a project related opencv using python language. I have a video data set named "VideoDataSet/dynamicBackground/canoe/input"  that stores the sequence of image frames and I would like to convert the sequence of frames from the file path to a video. However, I am getting an error when I execute the program. I  have tried various codecs but it still gives me the same errors, can any of you please shed some light on what might be wrong? Thank you.
This is my sample code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import glob as gb

filename = "VideoDataSet/dynamicBackground/canoe/input"

img_path = gb.glob(filename)

videoWriter = cv2.VideoWriter('test.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'), 
25, (640,480))

for path in img_path:
    img  = cv2.imread(path) 
    img = cv2.resize(img,(640,480))
    videoWriter.write(img)
print ("you are success create.")
```

This is the error:

```
Error prompt out:cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.4.1\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4044: error: (-215) ssize.width > 0 && ssize.height > 0 in function cv::resize
```

(Note: the problem occur with the img = cv2.resize(img,(640,480)))

Answer (score 0):

It is returning this error because you are trying to re-size the directory entry! You need to put:

```
filename = "VideoDataSet/dynamicBackground/canoe/input/*"
```

So that it will match all the files in the folder when you glob it. The error actually suggested that the source image had either zero width or zero height. Putting:

```
print( img_path )
```

In after your glob attempt showed that it was only returning the directory entry itself.

You subsequently discovered that although it was now generating a file, it was corrupted. This is because you are incorrectly specifying the codec. Replace your `fourcc` parameter with this:

`cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G')`

Comment: Nick,  your helping is appreciated. It is working. Thank

Comment: Dear Nick, i have some questions.  Currently the program code is successful executed and able to generate a video. However, the video  is unable to play it . Can i know what is the  problem may be?

Comment: It's difficult to say without having the file. Have you tried using ffmpeg? This usually tells you quite a lot if it is unhappy! BTW I thought you'd accepted my answer, but it is now showing as unaccepted again?

Comment: Have you tried `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G')` rather than your version?

Comment: To Nick, i am also not sure what problem is happen. At the early of the first time, it is work and able to play the video. But when i try modifies to other filename, the program code is run successfully and also can create a video at the file path location.  But, the problem is the video is unable to play it. About the solution that you suggested, i have tried, but still not work.

Comment: I tried it on some JPG images and it worked perfectly. When you say you are changing the filename, do you mean the filename of the movie file? You aren't changing the type are you? Some players won't like a name indicating one type and content of another. Can't spend any more time on this. Hopefully, given that I have got it working at least under some circumstances, you'll be minded to accept (again!).

Comment: Hi. As you've said twice in the comments above that my answer works, shouldn't you accept it? It's sort of how SO works too.

Comment: To Nick,  ya. i accept with your answer and my problem is solved where the saved video able to play now after i change cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G')  to cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID') or vlaue of -1. Would  i know what the problem may be ?

Comment: To Nick , here i have another questions need your help . I am read the saved video with write a program code. (cap = cv2.VideoCapture ('test.avi") ... from the saved filename after globed. But i getting following this error.

Error: OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed (chunk.m_size <= 0xFFFF) in cv::AVIReadContainer::readFrame, file D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.4.1\modules\videoio\src\container_avi.cpp, line 514.

May i know what problem may be and have any solutions that you are suggest that are able to solve?

Comment: To Nick, this the link that i create for the new question that i need your help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50574729/opencv-python-write-code-for-read-the-saved-video-cv2-videowriter

Comment: Hi. I will look at new question later. Have to work today.  This question isn't showing as accepted!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
img_path = gb.glob(filename)

videoWriter = cv2.VideoWriter('frame2video.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'), 25, (640,480))

for path in img_path:
    img  = cv2.imread(path)
    img = cv2.resize(img,(640,480))
    videoWriter.write(img)
```